# Save user interaction for video autoplay permission in SPA (similar to how YouTube does)

Tags: reactjs, youtube, html5-video, mobile-safari, autoplay

Currently I'm working with a React app where a user can click a link to be taken to a page to view a video.

However, even though the user has already interacted with the DOM, I still get this error:

`NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

However, on YouTube I see they have the functionality setup whereby if you click on a video thumbnail and are taken to the video you already have interacted with the DOM whereby Safari iOS will allow you to autoplay without having to unmute.

Does anyone know how I'd be able to 'preserve' my user interaction such that when I load a new page in my React app I am able to autoplay a video with sound (similar to how YouTube does it). I have read around on Stackoverflow but only seen suggestions about muting when the permission is not available which is not what I am going for, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't SPA mean single page application? So how does _"click a link to be taken to a page to view a video"_ get involved? I would expect an SPA to dynamically update contents (the `.innerHTML`) of some `<div>` object... Anyways try **(1)** After clicking maybe use `<iframe>` to display the video page on a layer above  the current page content (using `ZIndex` in Javascript) **(2)** It's possible, after clicking the thumbnail, you might have to trigger a `play + pause` to "kickstart" the autoplay. I think iOS expects the click event to specifically be for playing an a/v element)